# Как сделать флеш презентацию?

Tags: actionscript-2, flash, adobe, actionscript

Привет всем. Как можно создать презентацию покруче, чем PowerPoint? Например, типа prezi.com. Такие презентации можно сделать с помощью ActionScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- За воспроизведение и навигацию презентаций на prezi.com, отвечает своя библиотека, насколько помню именно на AS3. Технически там можно создавать собственные, загружая готовые страницы и блоки собранные во флеш файлы (SWF), но не знаю какие там ограничения для бесплатного аккаунта.
- Если делать презентацию с насыщенным интерфейсом (как у taxcom), то часто это делается в Adobe Flash Builder (MXML + AS3). Который кстати еще и позволяет делать презентации для iOS и Android.
- По моему скромному мнению, нельзя напрямую сравнивать PP и Flash, и в чем можно создать более крутую презентацию. Это в огромной степени зависит от рук, чем от самих инструментов.

Comment: на prezi.com т.е. используется полностью AS3?
Чем отличается AS3 от AS2 в двух словах? объектно-ориентированностью?

Comment: да, OOП это основное отличие, как языка

Comment: можно сразу с AS3 начинать, без AS2

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри **Adobe Presenter** встраивается в Power Point

Посмотри **Adobe captivate** как отдельное приложение

Получается много круче и динамичнее презентации + есть возможность сделать экспорт много куда, например Adobe Connect Pro.

Наверно реклама получилась. Но сам пользуюсь, удобно. Программировать ничего не нужно